# How to ensure file written with sed w command is closed

Tags: shell, sed

I'm using the sed 'w' command to get the labels from a TeX document using:

```
/\\label{[a-zA-Z0-9]*}/w labels.list
```

This script is part of a pipeline in which, later on, awk reads the file that sed has just written. e.g

```
cat bob | sed -f sedScript | awk -f awkScript labels.list -
```

Sometimes the pipeline produces the correct output, sometimes it doesn't (for exactly the same input file 'bob'). It's random.

I can only conclude that sometimes awk tries to read the file before sed has closed it properly. Is there anyway I can force sed to close the file at the end of the script, or any other suggestions as to what the problem may be?

Comment: Post your input data and what you like to get out of it.  It may that all can be done by one single `awk` command.  PS do not use `cat` with `sed`, `awk` and other program that can read data itself.

Comment: Dare say I could do it all in awk, but sed is easier for some things. I'm trying to convert somebodies pre-LaTeX era TeX files into standard LaTeX. It's a big job so unfortunately posting my input won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All stages in a pipeline run in parallel. This is an extremely important and defining feature of pipes, and there is nothing you can or should attempt to do in order to prevent or circumvent that.

Instead, you should rewrite your script so that all data dependencies are executed and finished in the order you need them to be. In the general case, you'd do

```
cat bob | sed -f sedScript > tempfile
cat tempfile | awk -f awkScript labels.list -
```

or equivalently in your case:

```
grep '\\label{[a-zA-Z0-9]*}' bob > labels.list
awk -f awkScript labels.list bob
```